# How can i fix this error that nodemon keep showing?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server, nodemon, node-mongodb-native

[how can fix this error on nodemon server, im just started learning MERN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKwdm.png)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the first line it the cause of the error

Answer (score 0):

You are using ES6 syntax import, either use require in the first line or add "type":"module" to your package.json file.

"type":"module" enables ES6 import/export functions on a NodeJs project.